# BirdNET Classifier Selection Tables

Tags: birdnet, classifier, files

I have a custom classifier that I created with BirdNET to run on recordings of continuous data written into hour-long files. I'm realizing that in the current format, BirdNET will assign a separate .txt for each detection table and that I can't merge them due to the begin/end time restarting for each file. I know Raven has Begin Path/Begin File/File Offset but as far as I can tell, there isn't a way to ask BirdNET to write everything into a single selection table.

For context, I am using the GUI and am running about 75 hour long files in the classifier at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [imp_raven](https://marce10.github.io/Rraven/reference/imp_raven.html) from the R package [Rraven](https://github.com/maRce10/Rraven) allows you to read and merge all .txt files at once and extract the name of the sound file from the name of the .txt. file with the argument  `name.from.file`

Comment: Thank you for the info! This is helpful and I will pursue this. Out of curiosity, I assume that even with the extraction of the name file, it's not adjusting the begin and end time to be accurate for using all the selection tables together, correct?

Comment: by default the function will pool all data together with the begin and end time as in the original .txt file. Not sure if this is what you are asking (?)

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for anyone who finds this helpful is the BirdNET developer recently added a function in the GUI that allows you to "Combine selection tables." You mark the check box and it will produce all of your separate detection tables, and then one at the end that combines them all together with the pooled times so that you can open it up along with all the sound files in one Raven window with only one selection table. I tried it out after I went through the R route and it works well.